# How to convert/transform column based on its mean value and reflect that on chart too in R?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following dataframe and stacked area chart based on it

```
df <- data.frame (Year  = c("2010", "2010",  "2010", "2010", "2011","2011","2011","2011","2012","2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013","2013"),
                  Sales = c(100000000,200000000,50000000,500000000,400000000,200000000,400000000,145000000,100000000,456000000,345000000,321000000,100000000,200000000,250000000,400000000),
                 Category = c("A", "B",  "C", "D","A", "B",  "C", "D","A", "B",  "C", "D","A", "B",  "C", "D"))

df$Year <- as.integer(df$Year)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, fill = Category)) +
  geom_area() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=2010:2013)
```

Now I want to somehow code the following:

1. If `mean(df$Sales)` > 1 000 000 Then `df$Sales/1 000 000`
2. If `mean(df$Sales)` > 1 000 & <1 000 000  Then `df$Sales/1 000`
3. Else do nothing

After I want to reflect that on ggplot y-axis:

- if the 1st condition is met label y axis as "Sales in Trillion"
- if the 2nd condition is met label y axis as "Sales in Billion" Else
- label y axis as "Sales in Million"

Comment: You can create couple of columns, i.e. `df %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(Mean = mean(Sales, na.rm = TRUE), Sales2 = case_when(between(Mean, 1000, 1000000)~ Sales/1000, Mean > 1000000 ~ Sales/1000000, TRUE ~ Sales), Label = case_when(between(Mean, 1000, 1000000)~ "Sales in Billion", Mean > 1000000 ~ "Sales in Trillion", TRUE ~ "Sales in Million"))`

Comment: I guess the `mean` would be based on each 'Year' or 'Category'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this if/else statement do the trick?

```r
library(tidyverse)


y_label = "Sales in Million"
if(mean(df$Sales)>1000000){
  df$Sales2 = df$Sales/1000000
  y_label = "Sales in Billion"
} else if(mean(df$Sales)>1000){
  df$Sales2 = df$Sales/1000
  y_label = "Sales in Trillion"
}

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales2, fill = Category)) +
  geom_area() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=2010:2013) + 
  ylab(y_label)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

PS : +1 for a good question formatting with a sample dataset

Comment: Can I apply to df too? So convert sales column as well

Comment: You can, although it is often better to apply modifications to another variable, so that you are always sure of what you are dealing with.